# Why can't I use 'delete' for this line?

Tags: c++, linked-list, free, delete-operator

I've started to learn [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) today, and I am trying to delete nodes.

```
void deleteEnd(Node* refNode) {
    Node* lastNode;
    lastNode = new Node;

    while((refNode->next)->next != NULL) {
        refNode = refNode->next;
    }
    lastNode = refNode->next;

    refNode->next = NULL;
    delete lastNode;
}

void deleteIndex(Node* refNode, int index) {
    Node *prev, *next, *deleted;
    prev = new Node;
    next = new Node;
    deleted = new Node;

    for(int i=1; i < index; i++) {
        refNode = refNode->next;
    }

    prev = refNode;
    deleted = prev->next;
    next = deleted->next;

    prev->next = next;
    free(deleted);
}
```

I can use `delete` in the first one, but when I try to use it in the second, it doesn't work. The terminal doesn't give any error messages.

I found some information on the Internet, but I couldn't really understand it.

This is my linked list:

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: You can't mix `free` with `new`. If you use `new` you must use `delete`. `free` must only be used to free memory you allocated with `malloc` (and related functions).

Comment: Please, please, please, *don't* use manual memory management in modern C++. *Please*. If your teaching material is telling you to do this, get newer material. If your teacher is telling you to do this, stop listening and get a better teacher.

Comment: Counting in C usually starts at 0, just in case you have a bug here: for(int i=1; i < index; i++). Also this line does not make much sense: deleted = new Node;

Comment: `lastNode = new Node; . . . lastNode = refNode->next;` leaks the allocated node, which you never had any use for. Also, does deleteEnd() need to deal with the case where there is only the one node in the list? It isn't written in a way that will do so.

Comment: Specifically, instead of manual memory management, a singly-linked list should be using `std::unique_ptr`, a managed single-ownership pointer that eliminates the need for `new` / `delete`. An argument could be made for `std::shared_ptr` if you want to be able to share tails (and are careful not to have cycles), but unique pointers are probably better for starting out.

Comment: Why are you creating a new node in `deleteEnd` when you are supposed to be deleting a node?

Comment: In `deleteEnd()`, you should check your pointers before dereferencing them.  For example, what if `refNode` is nullptr?  What if `refNode->next` is nullptr?

Comment: Obviously, manual memory management is not the way to go.  But in any kind of teaching material for C++, the user also needs to be taught what happens behind the scenes.  How it works.  And why automatic memory management is better.  Perhaps this person's teacher has elected to save that lesson until after they've struggled with the manual method for a while.

Comment: Classical Linked List data structures discuss using pointers or links; not smart pointers.  Simpler, IMHO, to understand than using smart pointers.

Comment: `It doesn't work` is not a very useful description of the problem. What did you see? What did you expect to see?

Comment: The best way to learn linked-lists in C++ is to learn how to use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) first, let it handle all of the gory details for you. You can delve into the deeper logic of pointers and memory management at a later time when your skills are ready for that.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: Some are still (forced to) [use Turbo C++](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra) (from the 1990s). For instance, as part of internships that are *required* in order to graduate. It sounds incredible, but this is from several sources, not just the given. For instance, [Joshua Fluke](https://www.youtube.com/c/JoshuaFluke1/videos) has also documented it.   The same part of the world also uses a version of English that is [more than 100 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wren_%26_Martin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments, there are several things wrong with this code. All issues are from the comments, none are found by me, all credit goes to [François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7359094/fran%c3%a7ois-andrieux), [Jesper Juhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5910058/jesper-juhl), [Sven Nilsonn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4847311/sven-nilsson), [Avi Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631266/avi-berger), and [Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews).

First, the code probably doesn't work because you mixed `new` and `free`. `new` is a C++ API function, while `free` is from C. Whenever you construct an object with `new`, which should not be that often with C++'s automatic memory management, you must free it with `delete`.

Second, when looping through a list, always start at 0. The only reason otherwise would be to start at the second item.

Third, in this passage:

```cpp
prev = new Node;
...
prev = refNode;
...
prev->next = next;
```

When you set `prev`, it is overwriting the previous value. If this is a pointer, as it is, then this causes a memory leak. Always `delete` it before overwriting.

Finally, in `deleteEnd`, as pointed out by Thomas Matthews, you are trying to dereference, or get the value from, the pointers, without checking if it is `nullptr`. If one is, it will cause undefined behavior, and can crash the program.